# what are the other methods available for SystemVerilog class similar to randomize(),pre_randomize() and post_randomize()?

Tags: system-verilog

I need the list of predefined in-built SystemVerilog class methods to make better use and understand of the possible things that can be done with the SystemVerilog class.

Comment: have you checked a system verilog manual?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), "Section 8. Classes", which contains everything you need to know about classes in SystemVerilog.